# dynamically building a datatable vs scriplets

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, datatable

Is it better to dynamically build a table then initiate a datatable, or use scriptlets and then build the datatable? I've read and rethought about how I should approach this. I currently have it working both ways, but I've reading about the advantages/disadvantages of ajax/back/forward/state... It's much easier with scriptlets since I really don't have to worry/handle those situations, especially on refresh/backbutton/forward, but with ajax I have to handle all that personally. What would you pick and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scriptlets are normally frowned upon because they break the MVC model,

this site explains it better
https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WhyNotUseScriptlets

Comment: Thanks for the link.. It's just that I'm pretty much picking up where other people have left for me, so should I actually go through and redo all their code or just reuse their code

Comment: not sure how big your project is, but I would try to at least not add to it if it's possible.